# Why does the C struct hack not work for C++ template declarations?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, language-lawyer, name-lookup

C has this fun hack where one name can be used to declare both a type and a function:

```
struct foo {};
void foo(void);
```

Now, any time I write `foo`, the compiler assumes I mean the function unless I prefix it with `struct`:

```
foo();  // call void foo(void)
struct foo bar;  // declare variable of type struct foo
```

This works great in C++ even with namespaces and nesting!
But it doesn't work with templates:

```
template <typename> void bar(void);
template <typename> struct bar {};
// error: conflicting declaration of template struct bar
// previous declaration: template void bar()
```

**Why?**

We already get to deal with disambiguators in dependent contexts:

```
typename foo<A>::b();
foo<A>::template b<C>();
```

It doesn't seem much of a stretch to apply the regular rules to ambiguous template names of this kind.

Suppose that having the same name is important to me. Could I somehow make this work?

Comment: You may want to add the `language-lawyer` tag, if you are looking for "chapter and verse" from the C++ standard, and perhaps a cross-reference to the C standard for nuances, differences, and similarities.

Comment: Good suggestion. Done.

Comment: Because it’s the **struct** hack, not the **template** hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wording is in [temp.pre-7](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#pre-7):

> A *class template shall not have the same name as any other template, class, function, variable, enumeration, enumerator, namespace, or type in the same scope* ([basic.scope]), except as specified in [temp.class.spec]...

None of the points in [temp.class.spec](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#class.spec) conflict with this example.

So, as it stands, you can't have the same name for a class template and a function template.

Comment: Did the committee consider removing this restriction as a way to implement CTAD?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; we already have CTAD. Also, I don't see this as a restriction, but as a feature. Ideally, I would like to not be able to do this even for  non-templates.

Comment: We have CTAD today, but between 14 and 17 this was an open question. Is `std::pair a(1, 2);` that much better than `auto a = std::pair(1, 2);` where the latter use is a function that works like `std::make_pair`?

Answer (score 4):

> Why?

The answer is in the body of the question. This works for classes and functions because in C there is a separate namespace for structure tags and function identifiers. If C++ aims to interoperate with C code, it must retain this behavior. One need only look at an API like the [`stat` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) taking a `struct stat` argument to realize why C++ retained the validity of such code. This working with namespaces is simply inline with C code residing in the global namespace (so `::stat` and `struct ::stat` should continue to work when needed).

However, in C++ the identifiers of class tags share a "namespace" with regular identifiers. And so the validity of this "hack" is achieved with  a special case in the C++ specification that simply hides classes when they would conflict.

> **[basic.scope.hiding]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.hiding#2) A class name or enumeration name can be hidden by the name of a
>   variable, data member, function, or enumerator declared in the same
>   scope. If a class or enumeration name and a variable, data member,
>   function, or enumerator are declared in the same scope (in any order)
>   with the same name, the class or enumeration name is hidden wherever
>   the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is visible.

It doesn't matter if the designers of C++ thought it was a good or bad idea. There is legacy code that should continue to be accepted as valid by C++ compilers for ease of inter-operating with certain systems.

But there is no legacy code dealing with templates that requires the same behavior. Templates are an entirely C++ construct (not related to C at all). And such, the language design doesn't have an outside constraint to add more special cases for template names too. And so it doesn't.

> Suppose that having the same name is important to me. Could I somehow make this work?

No way to make it work comes to mind.